# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent Relationship with custom table name

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

Im trying to access url property on files table by `$post->file->url`, but i'm getting **"Trying to get property of non-object"** error. My table and model is different because i can't use `File` as model name. is there something missing? I hope someone come with solution. here's my tables:

```
- posts:
 [PK] id 
      title
 [FK] featured_image 

 - files:
 [PK] id                
      title
      url
```

my model:

```
class TheFile extends \Eloquent 
{
   protected $table = 'files';

   public function post() {
     return $this->belongsTo('Post');
   }
}


class Post extends \Eloquent 
{   
  protected $table = 'posts';

  public function file() {
    return $this->hasOne('TheFile', 'id', 'featured_image');   
  }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my table name to medias, and my model to Media. Then put these code into `Post` model . It's works. The name of tables, model and method must be similar.

```
public function media() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Media', 'featured_image', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong but as I see it, you actually have the relationship the wrong way around here. If table `X` has one table `Y` then the FK field is on `Y` and related to the PK on `X`. But you have it the other way around.

As such you need to do one of two things:

1. Change your database to put `post_id` on `files` rather than having `featured_image` (points as `` file`.`id ``) on `posts`
2. Change your relationships to match your database structure:

   ```
   class TheFile extends \Eloquent
   {
       protected $table = 'files';

       public function post() {
           return $this->hasOne('Post');
       }
   }


   class Post extends \Eloquent
   {
       protected $table = 'posts';

       public function file() {
           return $this->belongsTo('TheFile');
       }
   }
   ```

   Obviously with your various field changes too if you aren't going to change the tables.

---

The basic rule of thumb is that if a table has the FK it's the 'belongs to' table. The other table is either 'has one' or 'has many'. The slight exception to this rule is obviously 'belongs to many' where a table can relate to another table where neither has an FK - but even that's a specialised version of the same rule - `X` 'has many' `X_Ys` and `Y` 'has many' `X_Ys` and `X_Y` belongs to `X` and `X_Y` belongs to `Y`. So it's just syntactic sugar really.

Comment: I think your answer is right. I put `belongsTo()` into `Post` and `hasMany()` to `TheFile`. But still not works. Maybe this is because table and model name doesn't match.